# Why is r sourcing my script when i want to save it?

Tags: r, debugging, save, rstudio

first time asking things here. Appreciate this community. I got a problem. If I want to save my script in RStudio either with the shortcut ctrl+s or if i click the icon on the top it only sources my active script. I even changed the shortcuts, but it didnt change anything. Is there anything i'm missing. Is this a known bug? Anyone can help me, i love the saving shortcut strg+s, thanks!

Comment: Please add a tag or some info when using RStudio?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Please note - your question tends to be off-topic here on SO!